# Can't find option to add a folder in the project from Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

[image]

When I select a folder and go to new option to add a new folder I couldn't find the option as shown in the screenshot I posted. None of my colleagues have experienced this issue before and are clue less upon this question

Comment: Maybe you can also post the screenshot of what you're getting

Comment: I'm trying to add a folder in the lib folder, I showed what options I am getting in the above screenshot already

Comment: I thought you were showing what you're trying to achieve. Actually, "Directory" there will create a folder

Comment: Oh thanks I was used to a folder option as I am using android studio after a long time... I'm grateful for your time and attention to my issue, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `New > Directory`. It will create a new folder.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)